# pip3 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS for a user

Tags: command-line, permissions, python

When performing

```
sudo pip3 install --user -U youtube-dl
```

I get 2 warnings:

1.
WARNING: The directory '/home/mue/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

2.
WARNING: The script youtube-dl is installed in '/home/mue/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Questions:

Concering 1. How can I resolve this?

Concering 2. Do you recommend ideed adding this to path. If yes: What is the command?

Comment: Please run the following command and then copy and paste the result in your question: `echo $PATH` Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `pip3` using the `sudo` command, the file that is installed is owned by `root` instead of your current user `mue`. The purpose of running `pip` or `pip3` with `--user` is so that you don't have to use `sudo` when you install stuff.

**First**, you can run the following command to restore ownership to your current user:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER $HOME/.local/bin/youtube-dl
```

**Next**, you can run the following command to properly update `youtube-dl`

```
pip3 install --user -U youtube-dl
```

**Finally**, if you do not get a warning about your path, you are done.

However, if you still get a warning that `youtube-dl` is not in your path, just log out and log back in to automatically fix this problem.

To explain, there is a conditional statement in the `~/.profile` file that automatically adds `~/.local/bin` to your PATH if and only if the path exists. Therefore, when you log out and log back in, it will automatically update your PATH to include your local directory.

Comment: If you run the `echo` command, make sure you use `tee -a` so that it will "append" to the file. If you mess up, you can always restore the original file using: `cp ~/.profilebackup ~/.profile`.